# Algorithm used for bucket lookup for hashcodes

Tags: java, algorithm, hashcode

In most cases, `HashSet` has lookup complexity **O(1)**. I understand that this is because objects are kept in buckets corresponding to hashcodes of the object.

When lookup is done, it *directly* goes to the bucket and finds (using equals if many objects are present in same bucket) the element.

I always wonder, how it *directly* goes to the required bucket? Which algorithm is used for bucket lookup? Does that add nothing to total lookup time?

Comment: The word is 'algorithm'. It is derived from a proper name. Abbreviation not permissible, indeed meaningless.

Comment: will take care from next time :)

Comment: Basically, buckets[o.hashCode() % buckets.length].

Comment: its basically accessing a index i from array. so no look up time to reach index i. i is calulated from hashcode%array.length ; and hashcode is being calculated from has function. 
although it takes some amount of constant time  and O(1) signifies that it doesen't depends on the size of elements.

Comment: each answer giving some more insight!! I can't accept them all :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From memory: the HashSet is actually backed by a HashMap and the basic look up process is:

- Get the key
- hash it (hashcode())
- hashcode % the number of buckets
- Go to that bucket and evaluate equals()

For a Set there would only be unique elements. I would suggest reading the source for HashSet and it should be able to answer your queries.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29

Also note that the Java 8 code has been updated and this explanation covers pre Java 8 codebase. I have not examined in detail the Java 8 implementation except to figure out that it is different.

Comment: It is not true that in a set there can be only one element per bucket. If you have a clash (two different elements with the same hash), they would end up in the same bucket. In the source code you linked you can even see that every bucket has a linked list of `Entry` elements.

Comment: You are right, what I meant was that there would be only unique keys in the set and no duplicates. Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> I always wonder, how it directly goes to the required bucket?

The hash code is [treated](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.hash%28java.lang.Object%29) and used as an index in to an array.

The index is determined by `hash & (array.length - 1)` because the length of the Java HashMap's internal array is always a power of 2. (This a cheaper computation of `hash % array.length`.)

Each "bucket" is actually a linked list (and now, possibly a tree) where entries with colliding hashes are grouped. If there are collisions, then a linear search through the bucket is performed.

> Does that add nothing to total lookup time?

It incurs the cost of a few loads from memory.

Comment: [`HashMap#hash`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.hash%28java.lang.Object%29) also mangles the hash to distribute the bits better

Answer (score 2):

Often, the algorithm is simply

```
hash = hashFunction(key)
index = hash % arraySize
```

See [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Hashing) on Hash Table for details.